# PM Changes to AM Java

Tags: java

I have a program that compute time interval.  When I input a time for timeTo with PM it changes to AM (when I debugged it).
Here is the code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter date: "); //ex: input 2016-02-16
    String dateFrom = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter time from: "); //ex input: 09:00 AM
    String timeFrom = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter time to: "); //ex input: 05:00 PM
    String timeTo = sc.nextLine();

    String substring = timeTo.substring(Math.max(timeTo.length() - 2, 0));
    String substring1 = timeFrom.substring(Math.max(timeFrom.length() - 2, 0));

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        c.setTime(dateformat.parse(dateFrom));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if ("AM".equals(substring) && "AM".equals(substring1)) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    } else if ("AM".equals(substring)) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    Date date1 = c.getTime();

    dateTo = dateformat.format(date1);

    Date d1 = new Date();
    Date d2 = new Date();

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateFrom + " " + timeFrom);
        d2 = format.parse(dateTo + " " + timeTo); // instead of 2016-02-16 05:00:00 PM
      //  it becomes 2016-02-16 05:00:00 AM
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    long diffMin = (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHour = (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;

    double d = (double) diffMin;
    double d3 = (double) diffHour; // -4.0 because 05:00 AM - 09:00 AM
```

Just like the sample above, the inputted value for timeFrom is 09:00 AM and for the timeTo is 05:00 PM it becomes 05:00 AM when passed to d2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong date-format-string. `HH` is "hour of day" in 24-hour-format, i.e. 0-23, nothing about AM/PM there (so anything <12 will be AM).

You have to use `hh` for 12-hour-format (assuming you need hours 1-12, for 0-11 use `kk`). Also you have to add the AM/PM-marker explicitly. So you should end up with

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
```

Take a look at the API-documentation for `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, it explains all the possible elements in the format-string.